# why my driver is not invoking when called by a constructor?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, pom.xml, webdriver-manager, chrome-options

I created a POM structure where `driver` is initialized in the main class and called in page classes using constructor. The problem is that the url is also passed from one of a page class called s1 landing page but its not invoking, only chrome is getting opened. URL is not getting passed.

Main class

```
public class Sample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String item = "ADIDAS ORIGINAL";
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));

        S1LandingPage S1landingPage = new S1LandingPage(driver);
        S1landingPage.Goto();
        S1landingPage.login("sanasameer.k@gmail.com","Sana@1234");
    }
}
```

S1LandingPage

```
public class S1LandingPage extends Sample1 {
    WebDriver driver;

    public S1LandingPage(WebDriver driver) {
        driver = this.driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); //to get driver for local variables made by find by 
    }

    @FindBy(id="userEmail")
    WebElement Uname;

    @FindBy(id="userPassword")
    WebElement pw;

    @FindBy(id="login")
    WebElement submit;

    public void login(String email, String passwrd) {
        Uname.sendKeys(email);
        pw.sendKeys(passwrd);
        submit.click();
    }

    public void Goto()  {
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/client/"); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pageObjects.S1LandingPage.Goto(S1LandingPage.java:45)
    at rahulshety.EndtoEnd.Sample1.main(Sample1.java:33)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment in the constructor is backwards.

```
public S1LandingPage(WebDriver driver) {
    driver = this.driver;
}
```

should be

```
public S1LandingPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
```

`this` references the current object, `S1LandingPage`. So, `this.driver` is the property `driver` on the `S1LandingPage` class and `driver` is the parameter `driver`.

See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) on `this` usage.